# Typescript enum in Angular ng-click event

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, typescript, enums

I have a TypeScript enum, for example:

```
enum AuthState { New, Exist, Forgot };
```

I have a button in .cshtml-file (ASP.NET MVC) with Angular ng-click:

```
<a ng-click="MyClick(AuthState.New)">...</>
```

I have a event handler in TypeScript auth.ts file:

```
...
$scope.MyClick = (state) => { ... }
...
```

Why parameter "state" in event handler is "undefined"? If in button do simple

```
onclick="alert(AuthState.Exist)"
```

result will be "1".

Comment: Error on compilation - can'not resolve

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't reference anything in your template that is not present in the $scope variable.

You can just add the enum to the scope and then you will be able to use it.

```
$scope.AuthState = AuthState;
```

Comment: please mark the answer as the correct one as well so future readers will know. :)